# How to match an optional group after a compulsory one that could include it

Tags: regex

I have a string input I need to parse, that has 2 different possible formats. It may look like either of the following:

- 2900 Sétubal (Portugal)
- 2900 Sétubal

I need a regex that will adequately split the postal code, city, and country (if provided) of both solutions.

This is the regex I've come up with so far.

`(?P<postal_code>\d*) (?P<city>.*)( \((?P<country>.*)\))?`

The problem is that regexes being read from left to right, the city group matches the country part of the string if it is provided, and I end up with something like :

```
postal_code = 2900
city = Sétubal (Portugal)
```

The output is right when I make the country group compulsory:

`(?P<postal_code>\d*) (?P<city>.*)( \((?P<country>.*)\))`

```
postal_code = 2900
city = Sétubal
country = Portugal
```

However, this regex does NOT match the 2nd possible format:

- 2900 Sétubal

I have tried using lookarounds, but I haven't succeeded. Any piece of advice will most definitely be welcome.

Comment: replace `(?P<city>.*)` with `(?P<city>[^()]*)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex extracts your data:

```
(\d+)\s+([^()]*)\s+(\(([^()]+)\))?
```

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/rYuhVb/1).

---

Based on your regex:

```
(?P<postal_code>\d+) +(?P<city>[^()]+)(?> +|$)(\((?P<country>[^()]+)\))?
```

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/rYuhVb/2).

Comment: Hi @virolino, and thank you for you contribution.I had thought of that solution, but believed it would be cleaner to address the "priority" each group may have in a regex. Do you know if this is possible ?

Comment: What do you mean by "priority"? The second regex delivers exactly what you need, decoding both formats.

Comment: Well, if I decide to exclude characters from the city group (namely braces in your example), this regex will not be able to work in all circumstances. I may not have been explicit enough when I asked the question, but my issue is with the fast that I would want the city regex to give back to an optional group (the country regex) when appropriate.

I would rather, if possible, not exclude any characters. :)

Comment: You must decide which characters are delimiters. I cannot think of any country which has paranthesis in its name. It is especially difficult to be so "generic", considering that cities names can have more than one word (Los Angeles, Buenos Aires), and country names as well (United Kingdom, United Arab Emirates, South Korea)... It is impossible to split by regex: `12345 Los Angeles North Korea`, `548 Dublin United Kingdom`, `9845 Buenos Aires Argentina` without clear delimiters. Or?

Comment: I accepted your answer since it does work in the case I presented, but I think I'll try and ask a better worded one when the need of giving back to an optional group will arise again ;)

Thanks for the time taken.

Comment: You are welcome. If you can explain better what you need, we are here. Explanation by examples might be able to work ;)